# Convert a REAL output into INTEGER

Tags: integer, fortran

```
PROGRAM ONE
IMPLICIT NONE

REAL::num1,num2,num3

READ(*,*)num1,num2
num3=num1+num2
WRITE(*,*)num3

STOP
END PROGRAM ONE
```

The WRITE statement displays a real number for "num3". What do I do so that it displays an integer value and I am not allowed to change it to integer in the declaration.

Comment: Convert real to integer before outputting it to the screen.

Comment: @Wildcat I know that, but how? I tried doing INTEGER(num3), but that didn't work. It gave me an error.

Comment: Cause it shoud be `int(num3)`.

Comment: @Wildcat int is integer in fortran

Comment: The name of the intrinsic type is `integer`. The name of the intrinsic function that converts `real` or `complex` number to `integer` is `int`.

Comment: @Wildcat okay. I didn't know that. Thanks! a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `real` number can be converted to an `integer` one using the `int` intrinsic function.

```
program one

  implicit none

  real :: num1, num2, num3

  read (*, *) num1, num2
  num3 = num1 + num2
  write (*, *) int(num3)

end program one
```

Note that `int` function simply truncates its real argument. More precisely, `int(a)` when `a` is of type `real` is calculated as follows:

- if |a| < 1, `int(a)` has the value 0;
- if |a| >= 1, `int(a)` is the integer whose magnitude is the largest integer that does not exceed the magnitude of `a` and whose sign is the same as the sign of `a`.

If this is not what you need, consider using `ceiling` or `floor` or `nint` intrinsic instead. The first one returns the least integer greater than or equal to its real argument, the second returns the greatest integer less than or equal to it, while the third - the nearest integer.